# Crystal reports drill down issue

Tags: crystal-reports

Ok so I made some changes and got somewhere.  However the issue is still their.  I figured out that when the main report is generated the Hyperlinks are not added to some of the fields.  However when we re-run the report again with the same parameter (we have a link that re-runs the report only changing the year parameter) those fields now have links.  This is very weird.  For an example I run the report for 2012 press the link to go back to 2011 and then press the link to go forward to 2012 the links now work in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only assign the 'ReportDocument' object to the CrystalReportViewer on the first page load? You should try storing your report document in session and ensure that on postbacks the CrystalReportViewer control's 'ReportSource' property is set again.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // do a bunch of Crystal Report's loading stuff
    ReportDocument yourReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    // etc, etc.
    // store the report document in server memory
    yourViewerControl.ReportSource = yourReportDocument;
    Session["theReportDocument"] = yourReportDocument;
}
else
{
    yourViewerControl.ReportSource = Session["theReportDocument"];
    yourViewerControl.Show();
}
```

Comment: Saned, I re-read your problem. I lack information about the nature of your report design. If it seems to be links *within the report* that navigate you around or cause updating, and the action updates on the _second attempt_ this could be a matter of the way your report filters or builds those links. I think not knowing what "links" you mean, is what is confusing. For example: If those are formula fields, that generate URLs, then the formula might be running BEFORE the data is updated to reflect 2011 versus 2012. Meaning, it could be the timing in the report processing. Elaborating will help.

Comment: Well to be honest as you probably can tell this I am really new to crystal reports.  Anyway I talked to the dev lead and it became his issue. Thanks for your help